# How to properly use the filter function of the Device Log in Visual Studio 2022 (Community)?

Tags: visual-studio, logging, visual-studio-2022, logcat

I am currently working on a .NET MAUI app and I'm running into issues during debugging with the Device Log printing way too much information.

In earlier versions there seem to have been filters directly integrated into the columns, but now there's only the search bar available, which doesn't seem to let me filter for e.g. log messages of type "Error", without also showing me all logs that include "Error" in the message.

[image: Example in Device Log]

Are there any special search terms I can use to get the functionality I want?

I've googled a bunch, but I couldn't find any results that describe how to use the search bar the way I would like it.

There is [Analyzing Device Logs in App Center Test](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/test-cloud/troubleshooting/device-logs), which offers some search terms but is ultimately useless for me. I've also found [Android Debug Log](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/debugging/android-debug-log?tabs=windows), which unfortunately also doesn't describe the search in more detail.